# Reading a text that has multiple new lines

Tags: java, text, newline, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I have the following text:

```
My name is Omer
//new line
I want to start my own personal project and achieve a lot with it
//new line
//new line
I also have problems that I encounter along the way but I know I will overcome them
//new line
Good
Bye
//new line
Bye
```

So that was the example above, I also want to use a BufferedReader.
Let's say my BufferedReader is called br.
Using br.readLine(), I can read lines from the console(I will input every single letter, I also use an InputStreamerReader)

If I do for example:

```
String line;
do {
line = br.readLine();
} while(line.lenght != 0)
```

It will stop after I enter a new line.

How can I read that text correctly? (I think that this is the first question that I ask here, sorry for any mistakes that I have maybe made)

Comment: `while((line=br.readLine())!=null){/*...*/}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    // your code here..
}
```

**Note:** don't do `do-while`, use `while`. Your input may be empty from the beginning, and you don't want to have a *Null Pointer Exception*.

Answer (score 0):

**just use readlines as readline just reads one line and return**

```
String line;
do {
line = br.readLines();
} while(line.lenght != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader#readLine` returns `null` when there is nothing left to read, so the following will work:

```
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    //do something with line
}
```

[`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) or [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) can be used to simplify this.

---

If you are reading input from the console, you can enter a string like "exit" to indicate that the program should stop reading.

```
while(!(line=br.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
    //do something with line
}
```

Comment: returns null when there is nothing left to read -> Alright, but how can I stop reading after I entered my text? It keeps asking me to input more and more endlessly :D